# Spring boot custom field validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

I am trying to make the following validations:

- Checking in an email exists in the database.
- Checking in an username exists in the database.
- Checking if the password confirmation is entered correctly.

I am using a class for validation. Example:

```
public class RegisterRequest {

    @NotNull(message = "Please enter an email")
    @Email(message = "Not a valid email")
    @JsonProperty("email")
    public String email;

    @NotNull(message = "Please enter a name")
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;

    @NotNull(message = "Please enter a password")
    @JsonProperty("password")
    public String password;

    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("password_confirmation")
    public String passwordConfirmation;
}
```

This is all working fine until this far.
But now I want to build in the password validation(Check if 2 password's match). I will only use this one time, so I think it is unnecessary to create a whole Annotation for this.
How can I do this without the use of an Annotation.

The solution I found that comes closes to what I want is to use `@AssertTrue` on a method that validates the passwords:

```
@AssertTrue("Passwords don't match")
public boolean checkPasswords() {
    return this.password.equals(this.passwordConfirmation);
}
```

This works but it is not linked to a field, but it is a global error.
So I can't find out to what field the `Passwords don't match` error belongs.
Is there a way to link the `checkPasswords` validation to a field?

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-password-example/

Comment: @StanislavL this link 7 years old and talking about old way of validation. Note that author put `bean-validation` tag and using JSR-303 annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This works but it is not linked to a field, but it is a global error.

Yes, it's a global error because you're working with a whole object.

> How can I do this without the use of an Annotation.

I don't know such ways. You have to write your own validator in order to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks I have written my own: https://github.com/jwz104/validation It is a long way from finishing but the base is there.

Comment: I wrote my own a few years ago too: [FieldsMatchValidator](https://github.com/php-coder/mystamps/blob/581412f565c71ecc482da5542e7ff77fe6a91a7f/src/main/java/ru/mystamps/web/support/beanvalidation/FieldsMatchValidator.java) and [UniqueLoginValidator](https://github.com/php-coder/mystamps/blob/581412f565c71ecc482da5542e7ff77fe6a91a7f/src/main/java/ru/mystamps/web/support/beanvalidation/UniqueLoginValidator.java)